# How to generate previous months orders from db using linq or lambda?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have tried this:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
var lastMonth = ( from lm in db.Orders
                  where lm.Saved> date
                  select lm).ToList();
```

This generates this month and previous month. I only need last month, how can I solve this using linq or lambda?

Comment: Do you want all records between the first and last days of the last month? or from `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)` (18/9/2016) until the last day of last month?

Comment: This gives all the orders from previous month and this month because you have specified the conditon `lm.Saved> date`.

Comment: Yes all records between the first and last days of the last month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to generate the minimum and maximum dates and query records between those 2 dates.

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var max = new Date(today.Year, today.Month, 1); // first of this month
var min = max.AddMonths(-1); // first of last month
var lastMonth = ( from lm in db.Orders
                  where lm.Saved >= min && lm.Saved < max
                  select lm).ToList();
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Thank you :)